# Deserialize JSON to an array of objects, instead of to one object list

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Apologies for the probably confusing title. I'm new to JSON and I'm working on a Web Application with a piece of software which interfaces with the API. I have control of both.

My applications needs to enumerate a list of "Clients" and their "Projects". Currently it returns the following:

```
{
  "clients": [
    {
      "client_id": "1",
      "client_name": "Client1",
      "projects": [
        {
          "client_project_id": "1",
          "client_project_title": "WidgetsA",
          "client_project_client": "1",
          "client_project_status": "1"
        },
        {
          "client_project_id": "11",
          "client_project_title": "WidgetsB",
          "client_project_client": "1",
          "client_project_status": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "client_id": "11",
      "client_name": "Client11",
      "projects": [
        {
          "client_project_id": "31",
          "client_project_title": "Install",
          "client_project_client": "11",
          "client_project_status": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "client_id": "21",
      "client_name": "Client21",
      "projects": [
        {
          "client_project_id": "61",
          "client_project_title": "Marketing",
          "client_project_client": "21",
          "client_project_status": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "client_id": "31",
      "client_name": "Client31",
      "projects": [
        {
          "client_project_id": "71",
          "client_project_title": "Fire Everyone",
          "client_project_client": "31",
          "client_project_status": "1"
        },
        {
          "client_project_id": "81",
          "client_project_title": "Buy A Company",
          "client_project_client": "31",
          "client_project_status": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can deserialize this easily enough to an object using the following JSON.NET code:

```
MyObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(response);
```

However, this only works if my objects look like the following:

```
  [Serializable, JsonObject]
    internal class MyObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("clients")]
        internal List<ClientObject> ClientList = new List<ClientList>();
    }


 internal class ClientObject
    {

        [JsonProperty("client_id")]internal string ClientID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("client_name")] internal string ClientName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("projects")] internal List<ProjectObject> ProjectList = new List<ProjectObject>();
    }
```

(NB: I've changed the names of a lot of properties and objects for privacy, so apologies for any mistakes added)

What I really want to be able to do is use the following code:

```
List<ClientObject> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClientObject>>(response);
```

But no matter how I format the JSON response, JSON.NET throws an error stating that the JSON is not an array. Can anyone advise where I'm going wrong, or what I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: of the json string is not an array.

Comment: Your json format is "object" format - `{"clientList": [ {client1properties}, {client2properties}] }`. You need change returned json to be a collection format `[{client1properties}, {client2properties}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is an object, that contains a field that is an array. You cannot directly convert it to array.

You can use this JSON I suppose:

```
[
    {
      "client_id": "1",      
    },
    {
      "client_id": "2",      
    }
]
```

But seriously, it does not hurt to have a proper response object that contains an array inside. I would rather us it.

Comment: Are there any particular pros/cons either way?

Comment: No, not really I guess. It's just a matter of style, I guess I prefer more explicit ones (e..g you can have the name then, i.e. `clients` in your case)

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, your JSON is an object, not array, so it cannot be deserialized directly to a list.

But you can still use [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/linqtojson.htm) to get your clients list from JSON:

```
string json = @"...";
JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);
List<ClientObject> clients = data["clients"].Select(c => c.ToObject<ClientObject>()).ToList();
```